# Alterar idioma de gráfico AmCharts

Tags: javascript, html, chart

Tenho o seguinte gráfico

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = generatechartData();
function generatechartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 150 );
  var visits = -40;
  var b = 0.6;
  for ( var i = 0; i < 150; i++ ) {
    // we create date objects here. In your data, you can have date strings
    // and then set format of your dates using chart.dataDateFormat property,
    // however when possible, use date objects, as this will speed up chart rendering.
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + i );
    if(i > 80){
        b = 0.4;
    }
    visits += Math.round((Math.random()<b?1:-1)*Math.random()*10);

    chartData.push( {
      date: newDate,
      visits: visits
    } );
  }
  return chartData;
}

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series.fillOpacity = 0.1;

// Create a range to change stroke for values below 0
var range = valueAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.value = 0;
range.endValue = -1000;
range.contents.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(4);
range.contents.fill = range.contents.stroke;
range.contents.strokeOpacity = 0.7;
range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.1;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

chart.language.locale = am4lang_pt_BR;
chart.dateFormatter.language = new am4core.Language();
chart.dateFormatter.language.locale = am4lang_pt_BR;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/lang/pt_BR.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Porém gostaria de deixar as datas em português.
Tentei o seguinte:

No arquivo html

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/lang/pt_BR.js"></script>
```

No arquivo js

```
 chart.language.locale = am4lang_pt_BR;
 chart.dateFormatter.language = new am4core.Language();
 chart.dateFormatter.language.locale = am4lang_pt_BR;
```

Mas não funcionou, as datas continuam em inglês.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque o arquivo de idioma na linha abaixo do arquivo animated.js.

Para bom entendedor, bastava a explicação acima, mas por recomendações, segue mais detalhes:

A ordem do script influencia no resultado final e em seu código está como abaixo

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/lang/pt_BR.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
```

Então, altere como a seguir

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/lang/pt_BR.js"></script>
```

Espero que esteja claro o suficiente, caso não esteja, tento enviar um desenho feito no paint. Abraços.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/245065)

Comment: Não responde? Você testou antes de afirmar isso sobre minha resposta? Testei e funcionou.

Comment: Sua resposta está muito ampla, Guttemberg, por isso o motivo da sinalização do gmsantos. Recomendo especificar melhor sua resposta, como por exemplo: em qual "linha abaixo do arquivo".

Comment: André Filipe, "na" linha abaixo, especifica a linha. Caso estivesse "em alguma linha", é que seria amplo. No entanto, creio que a resposta foi clara agora. Caso não esteja, podem excluir, ou eu mesmo excluirei sem problemas, pois a esta altura, nem mesmo o autor do tópico deve ter interesse na resposta. Abraços